# Laravel notification sent with no content and wrong subject

Tags: laravel

I've created this notification in `app/Notifications`:

```
class StatisticsExportNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    use EmailNotificationViewHTMLTrait;

    protected $links;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct($links)
    {
        $this->links = $links;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            MailChannel::class
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        list($subject, $viewData) = $this->getNotificationViewHTML('statistics_export', $notifiable, ['links' => $this->links]);

        return (new MailMessage())
            ->subject($subject)
            ->view('mail.main', compact('viewData'));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to send it like this:

```
$member->notify(
        new StatisticsExportNotification('testing')
    );
```

Right now, the content of the email HTML template is just:

```
{{links}}
```

But I have confirmed that the same issue occurs if the HTML is just a hardcoded string and if I don't try to pass any variables to it.

That issue being, it seems to me that the `toMail` method is somehow not being called at all here. When I do `logger()->debug($links)` inside the class constructor, it logs the value of the variable. But when I do `logger()->debug('test')` inside `toMail()`, it doesn't log anything!

If I hardcode the subject and content inside the method, it makes no difference:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $subject = "foo";
        $viewData = ["test" => "bar"];

        return (new MailMessage())
            ->subject($subject)
            ->view('mail.main', compact('viewData'));
    }
```

Whatever I do, the system sends the notification to the member's email, but the subject is "Statistics Export Notification" and the email body is empty!

What `getNotificationViewHTML` does is get the template of the message and populate it with the data we pass to it, but again, this code seems to never come into play at all. I've tried adding logging inside that method as well, and even putting in code that I know would throw an error if executed, but whatever I do, the notification sends with the same default subject and the same empty body.

Comment: Have u tried restarting you queue and running php artisan config:cache?

Comment: No, but how would that help? I've added/edited notifications before and didn't need to restart anything.

Comment: Because the queue process does not get that cahnges after u start it. So when u restart it the queue process will be loaded with the updated configs. I will recommand just try it once.

Comment: Tried it, didn't help.

Comment: Can you try {{{ }}} instead of {{ }} in your mail templete?

Comment: That doesn't (and can't) help. All other templates have the same syntax.

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using? 5.4? I'm trying to reproduce with 5.7

Comment: So far, when I hardcode the subject with variable, and restart queue with `php artisan queue:restart` to take latest change, it set `foo` as new subject.

Comment: @jovan any update on this? Did you check that your view file has `.blade` like `views/mail/main.blade.php` ?

Comment: @KeitelDOG I was away for two days, I will be testing these suggestions today.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your Issue, and I think I did somehow, but I can never be sure 100% until you test it yourself. So Here is some advices :

1- While testing, try using direct array instead of compact to convert it

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $subject = "foo";
    $viewData = ["links" => "Here is the Links"];

    return (new MailMessage())
        ->subject($subject)
        ->view('mail.main', $viewData);
}
```

2- In your `mail.main` view file, the correct syntax should embrace the variable name with `$` :

```
{{ $links }}
```

and not just

```
{{ links }}
```

3- Probably your real issue there, MAKE SURE your view file has `.blade.php` so that Blade is allowed to parse codes like `@section`, `@yield`, `{{$links}}`, etc. Your mail view filename should be :

```
views/mail/main.blade.php
```

4- DO NOT FORGET TO RESTART QUEUE Codes after changing any codes from Statistics Notification file. And this should set the `$subject` successfully :

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

and after start it again

```
php artisan queue:work  --tries=3
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the core of the issue here. The toMail() function is somehow never taken into consideration! Forget the template for now, if I hardcode the subject and title in toMail, and restart the queue, and try it again, still nothing changes! It's always the same generic title and the same empty email body.

Comment: @jovan Have you tried on an empty project with a different Laravel version to see if it's a bug? Cause I create easily your case in a Laravel 5.7.9 an everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping out your `via` method with an array of strings:

```
/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the definition of `getNotificationViewHTML` return an array [subject, html]?

The `list` keyword unpacks an array's elements, starting with the 0th element. Since you say the subject and content are wrong, my money is on the return value of getNotificationViewHTML.

To test, just hardcode getNotificationViewHTML like this:

```
public function getNotificationViewHTML()
{
    return ["This Is the Subject", "<h1>This is My Message</h1>"];
}
```

If your mail then comes through with those values, you need to tailor your getNotificationViewHTML return value to match the example's format.